# Returning javascript variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there is an easy way to return time difference from a javascript function and then call it in php.

I have something like this at the moment:

```
function getDiff() {
    $("#timeTo").on('keyup', function() {
        var timeTo = $("#timeTo").val();
        var timeFrom = $("#timeFrom").val();
        var diff = parseFloat(timeTo) - parseFloat(timeFrom);
    });

    return diff;    
}
```

I then want to call getDiff() in PHP to get the value of diff and i tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
$timeDiff = getDiff();
```

Comment: You do realize PHP runs on the server and JavaScript (usually) runs on the client.  You'll need some sort of mechanism (such as HTTP) to transfer data between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `diff` to PHP using AJAX.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function getDiff() {
    $("#timeTo").on('keyup', function() {
        var timeTo = $("#timeTo").val();
        var timeFrom = $("#timeFrom").val();
        var diff = parseFloat(timeTo) - parseFloat(timeFrom);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test.php",
          data: { difference: diff }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the only thrustable way to do this would be using websockets - there are examples of applications to PING and monitoring the latency between the client and the server. In the same way, you would mean discarding the latency to get the real.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is only executed in the Browser.
PHP is only executed on the server.
You cannot call Javascript methods from within PHP scripts.
You could eventually send that value with an AJAX request or with a POST or GET request.

Answer (score 0):

xhr:

```
var x=(window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){
  alert(x.responseText);
}}
x.open('GET','phpdiff.php?q='+diff,true);x.send();
```

phpdiff.php

```
echo$_GET['q'];
//calculate your diff
```